# Prove or disprove: If $H$ is a normal subgroup and cyclic and $G/H$ are cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

> Prove or disprove: If $H$ is a normal subgroup and cyclic and $G/H$ are cyclic, then $G$ is cyclic.

I don't understand the quotient group $G/H$ being cyclic. What does it mean? From what I understand, $G/H$ is a group that includes groups and not elements, right?

I know that the reverse is right (If $G$ is cyclic then $G/N$ is cyclic.)

How do I disprove it?

Comment: Elements of $G/H$ are sets of the form $aH$ for some $a \in G$, and $G/H$ is itself a group by defining $(aH)(bH) := (ab)H$ for any $a$ and $b$ in $G$. So, $G/H$ is *cyclic* if there exists $g \in G$ such that $$G/H = \{\dots,(gH)^{-2},(gH)^{-1},(gH)^0,gH,(gH)^2,\dots\}.$$

Comment: Elements of $G/H$ aren't groups except for $H$.

Comment: What groups do you know which aren't cyclic?

Comment: real numbers I mean (R)

Comment: I should think about basic examples of groups ...

Comment: The Klein four group may be the simplest counter-example.

Comment: You could think of the even numbers and the odd numbers, or the integers modulo $3$ (with addition as the operation) to see the kind of sets (not groups) involved when you take a quotient.

Comment: If you understand that $G/H$ is a group, and if you understand what it means for a group to be cyclic, then what does it matter whether certain elements of $G/H$ are, themselves, dogs, or cats, or groups, or cosets, or whatever they are? They are elements of the group $G/H$, and what it means for the group $G/H$ to be cyclic is that it has one element that generates the whole gorup.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun one!

To address the question in the title, note that:

- $D_4$ is not cyclic,
- the group $C_4 = \{\rho_0, \rho_{90}, \rho_{180}, \rho_{270} \}$ (the rotation subgroup) is cyclic, and a normal subgroup of $D_4$
- $D_4/C_4$ is of order $2$ and is thus cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Of the small finite non-cyclic groups $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ of order $8$ is the smallest which ***doesn't*** have a cyclic normal subgroup with a cyclic quotient.

Note that a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal. Do you know any groups which have a cyclic subgroup of index $2$? If they are not themselves cyclic, they will be counterexamples.

You should be able to find both abelian and non-abelian examples of small order, and also some general cases. Also try to find a small example of odd order (the smallest non-abelian example of odd order has order $21$).

This is a test and suggestion to develop a repertoire of examples of groups with/without interesting properties. Working hands-on will teach you a great deal about what is possible and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest counterexample is Klein's $4$-group, $G=\{e,a,b,ab\}$. Take e.g. $H=\{e,a\}$; then, $H\unlhd G$, $H\cong C_2$ and $G/H\cong C_2$ (it's worthwile to explicitly write the two elements of the quotient, and squaring the nonidentity one), but $G$ is not cyclic.